# Numbers $n$ with $n,n+2$ coprime to $p_k\#$ on $[1, p_k\#]$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

In the context of sieving for twin primes ($p\#$ is the primorial function) the following seems true.

> The number of $n$ such that $n, (n+2)$ are coprime to $p_k\#$ for $n=1,2,...,~p_k\#$ is $\prod_{i=2}^k (p_i-2).$

Calculation of the first 7 products and a bit of luck in OEIS suggest this is true but it does not seem so easy to prove. I notice that $n+2$ is a simple permutation of $GCD(n,p_k\#)$ and so maybe using characters? Partly I am posting this because I haven't seen it before so someone else might find it interesting. It does not lead (directly) to a useful sieve because $p_k\#$ grows too fast but probably it has been considered somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me consider $p_k$ primes.

According to the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html)
every number $n$ from $1$ to $p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ is uniquely determined by
the set of its $k$ remainders $r_i$ when $n$ is divided by $p_i$.

In practice to every choice of remainders $r_i$ corresponds one and only one number $n$ from $1$ to $p_1p_2\cdots p_k$.

So, we can ask, in how many ways can we choose remainder $r_i$ ? We want it different from 0, otherwise $n$ is divisible by $p_i$ and we want it different from $p_i-2$, otherwise $n+2$ is divisible by $p_i$.

So, apart the case of $p=2$ in which only the remainder 1 is admissible,
in all the other cases there are $p_k-2$ possible remainders.

Hence, the number of sets of "good" remainders (and thus the number of "good" pairs) is just 
$$(p_2-2)(p_3-2)\cdots (p_k-2)
$$

as you imagined.

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposed to answer the question here. So I will mention that the proof is not hard, it can be reached by basic reasoning around the symmetry and divisibility of the numbers, without explicitly using the remainder theorem. Hint: what happens when expanding from $k$ to $k+1$? You're basically creating $p_{k+1}$ duplicates of the previous configuration; some of the duplicates are however divided by $p_{k+1}$. Since another and shorter proof has already been given, I do not go into more detail on this.

What I really want however, is some commentary on this entire concept.
I'm glad I found out, by some searching, that somebody else had found this formula, that I have also been playing with. I will create a linked question.

Comment: +1. Welcome to our community!