# Finding a number of twin primes less than a certain number

Tags: number-theory

I was doing some problems on number theory, and I came across the following question: "How many twin primes less than 100 exist?" I was wondering if anyone could tell me what method would be used to solve this problem and others too.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this fact could come in handy or not: All twin primes apart from $(3,5)$ are of the form $6n\pm1$

Comment: Tables of small primes are very easy to find. Dig up one of them and _count_ how many twins there are below 100.

Comment: @ Mufusa : this is how they build their generating function of $T(x)$ the number of twin primes $< x$, no ?

Comment: These are the primes smaller than $100$, help yourself: $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $11$, $13$, $17$, $19$, $23$, $29$, $31$, $37$, $41$, $43$, $47$, $53$, $59$, $61$, 
$67$, $71$, $73$, $79$, $83$, $89$, $97$.

Comment: Also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=twin+primes+less+than+1000) works.

Comment: One would use the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find all primes under a given limit, and then run through the list to count the twins.

Comment: I recommend a computer...  This is probably the quickest way to do this. Do you have a general idea about how you plan on solving this?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can count the twin primes less than $n$ by hand.
2. You can find the number of twin primes less than $p_k!!$ (the product of primes not exceeding the $k$th prime) using the sieve S as modified in S' in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664722/twin-prime-sieve), *but there may not be any twin primes* beyond some very large $n$. In any event the size of the numbers makes computation (of the prime pairs, if not their cardinality) difficult for even modest $k.$
3. For small $n$ the sieve S above is useful. For the original question, by S there are 3 pairs (n,n+2) co-prime to $2,3,5$ on an interval of length 30. Then we have 12 co-prime pairs on (1,120) and so on $[1,100]$  we cannot have more than 12 pairs of twin primes. We can quickly compute co-prime pairs and  we see that 10 pairs are in fact twin primes, 8 less than 100.
4. Version II of Chen's 1973 theorem says that for any positive even integer $h$ there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+h$ is either a prime or semiprime. Since $h$ can be 2 there are infinitely many such pairs which are potentially twin primes. Up to boundaries which would not be much use for the OP, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen%27s_theorem) may be the best we can currently say regarding existence of infinitely many twin primes. This is just a gloss on 2 above.

Halberstam and Richert's *Sieve Methods* is a really good resource for questions in this area.

Comment: Zhang's theorem is also worth mentioning but I think (4) is far enough afield.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.Only I think to see Wilson's theorem and (because of primes less that $100$) looking for solutions of the two congruences
$$(p-1)!+1\equiv 0 \pmod p$$ $$(p+1)!+1\equiv 0 \pmod {p+2}$$
Paying some attention this could work, I guess. However for primes $p$ larger, verification in tables of primes or twin primes could be the only "method"

Comment: Well, I can easily recite the primes up to $100$ just by remembering the multiplication table and simple divisibility rules (the only "difficult" number is $91=7\cdot 13$). I don't think that computing the factorial is a very efficient method... it's even worse than trial division.

Comment: I agree with you, however remember I told about some "method" and not a method. Regards.