# On number configurations coprime to $p_k\#$ on $[1, p_k\#]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Being a non-mathematician, I seek guidance and commentary regarding the formula discussed here:
[Numbers $n$ with $n,n+2$ coprime to $p_k\#$ on $[1, p_k\#]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662742/numbers-n-with-n-n2-coprime-to-p-k-on-1-p-k/3911936#3911936)

Repeating it here:

> The number of $n$ such that $n, (n+2)$ are coprime to $p_k\#$ for $n=1,2,...,~p_k\#$ is
>
> $\prod_{i=2}^k (p_i-2).$

I'm glad I finally did the search and found out that somebody else had found this formula, that I have also been playing with for some considerable time.
List of questions.

1. Is "$p_k\#$" a generally adopted notation for the product of a sequence of primes? (I think I like it.)
2. The formula can be generalized, and I assume this is known?
   [For plain numbers (potential primes in the interval)]

   The number of $n$ that are coprime to $p_k\#$ for $n=1,2,...,~p_k\#$ is $\prod_{i=1}^k (p_i-1).$
   [For odd number pairs (potential twin primes)]: as above, $\prod_{i=2}^k (p_i-2).$
   [For potential "quad primes"]The number of $n$ such that $(n, n+2, n+6, n+8)$ are coprime to $p_k\#$ for $n=1,2,...,~p_k\#$ is $\prod_{i=3}^k (p_i-4).$
   [etc...?]
3. I suppose this "law" is not established or important enough to have a name?
4. I would like to have a short name for the concept of a "potential prime" or "prime candidate" obtained by establishing it coprime against $p_k\#$ (or against a more general set of divisor primes). I personally called it "prime candidate with respect to $p_k$" in my private notes. (OK, "coprime to $p_k\#$" is pretty short and is perhaps the term I was looking for. Are there other names for it?)
5. I assume the following is also well known (please confirm).
   The classical proof of infinite primes: Assume the last and largest prime is $p_k$. Observe that $p_k\#-1$ is coprime to $p_k\#$. Demonstrate the contradiction and conclude the assumption is false.
   The point: The plain version of the discussed formula generalises this by demonstrating that there are many numbers above $p_k$ coprime to $p_k\#$; any one of them leads to the proof.
   In particular, the first such number larger than $p_k$ has to be a true prime since no other divisors can exist.
6. I assume the following observation is also well known?
   In the hunt for twin primes; if a number pair is found to be coprime to $p_k\#$, larger than $p_k$ and smaller than $p_{k+1}^2$, then it is a true twin prime. (Which obviously means $n >= p_{k+1}$.)
   Proving that such a pair can always be found would prove the twin prime conjecture.
7. Is there a "quad prime conjecture"?
8. Is there a generalised conjecture that given any pattern of numbers that are all prime, this pattern is going to repeat itself an infinite number of times? Or a weaker conjecture of non-uniqueness: any pattern will eventually repeat.

Comment: Yes $x\# = \prod_{p \le x} p$ (in number theory $\prod_p$ means over the primes)  is standard. The name is 'Chinese remainder theorem' :-) The generalization of the twin prime conjecture is Hardy's first conjecture, often called k-uple, then there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture You should look at the constant given by Hardy, it is based on the random model for the primes (that the distribution of your $n$ is merely the same in the short interval $[p_k,p_k^2]$ as in $[1,p_k\#]$, so we can apply the CRT stuffs to the twin prime sieve that you described)

Comment: A piece of advice, if you want to get an answer, try to ask one question maybe 2 at a time.

Comment: Thank you @reuns for your very constructive and helpful comment! I do not agree that "the name is CRT", but yes the sieves are direct consequences of CRT. I have now learned that at least the first variant is a case of Euler's totient function: $phi(p_k\#)=$ the product of all $(p_i-1)$. The other variants do not seem to directly fit Jordan's generalization of the totient function.